# ADOdb and null fields

Tags: php, sql-server, adodb

I'm using the last version of ADOdb PHP (5.18) to make some queries in a SQL Server database.

I select data in this way:

```
$rS = $localDb->Execute($sql);
if (!$rS) {
  echo "Error: " . $localDb->ErrorMsg() . "\n";
}
else {
  $tot = $rS->RecordCount();
  echo " " . $tot . " record da inserire...\n";

  while (!$rS->EOF) {
    $id = $rS->fields['id'];
    $field1 = $rS->fields['field1'];
    $field2 = $rS->fields['field2'];
    $rS->MoveNext();
  }
}
```

All works, and I fetch data, but when a field in the database's current row is NULL, the relative element in $rS->fields has the value of the value of the last not-NULL row for the same field.

This is a big problem because I don't have correct data in the current row.

I tried search for this problem but I did not find any solution.

Coud you help me, please?

Comment: I realized now that 5.19 was released, and this was a bug which is fixed in this version:
* adodb: GetRowAssoc will return null as required. See [http://phplens.com/lens/lensforum/msgs.php?id=19289](http://phplens.com/lens/lensforum/msgs.php?id=19289)

Answer (score 0):

Look into adodb5/adodb.inc.php and find the GetRowAssoc function. It should be the following defintion:

```
function GetRowAssoc($upper=ADODB_ASSOC_CASE_UPPER)
{
    $record = array();
    if (!$this->bind) {
        $this->GetAssocKeys($upper);
    }
    foreach($this->bind as $k => $v) {
        if( array_key_exists( $v, $this->fields ) ) {
            $record[$k] = $this->fields[$v];
        } elseif( array_key_exists( $k, $this->fields ) ) {
            $record[$k] = $this->fields[$k];
        } else {
            # This should not happen... trigger error ?
            $record[$k] = null;
        }
    }
    return $record;
}
```